# How to link many files with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

How Is simple way to link files in this tree files with cmake?

```
root
 ├── 1
 │   └── 2
 │       └── 3
 ├── 2
 │   └── 3
 └── 3
 └── 4
     └── 5
         └── 6
             └── 7
```

How can I better than this example?

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" "*/*.cpp" "*/*/*.cpp" "*/*/*/*.cpp" "*/*/*/*/*.cpp")

add_executable(a.out ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: GLOB does support recursion with GLOB_RECURSE

Comment: It works! Thanks.